# The specified argument value for the function is not valid. [ Argument # = 1,Name of function(if known) = isnull ]

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I want to select from a table where a column matches a given parameter. If the parameter is null, I want to select all records from the table. The relevant code below is what throws this error.

```
    private static string _dbJobCreate = 
"CREATE TABLE Job (jID int primary key identity(1,1), jAddress nvarchar(64) not null);";

    private static string _dbJobSelect = 
"SELECT jID FROM Job WHERE jAddress = @jAddress OR @jAddress IS NULL";

    public static DataTable GetJobs(string jAddress)
    {
        SqlCeParameter pjAddress = new SqlCeParameter();
        pjAddress.ParameterName = "@jAddress";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jAddress))
        {
            pjAddress.Value = jAddress;
        }
        else
        {
            pjAddress.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }

        return ExecuteDataTable(_dbJobSelect, pjAddress);
    }
```

Exception: `The specified argument value for the function is not valid. [ Argument # = 1,Name of function(if known) = isnull ]`

How can I efficiently accomplish this without error in SQLCE?

Comment: Useful discussion:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/83821937-3929-4901-a78e-b675cf8a70ca/how-to-send-a-null-value-as-a-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to select all rows from the database, and filter down the rows in .NET if a parameter was passed in. This could become troublesome if there were a large number of jobs, although I suppose I'd move to a real database if that ever happens.

```
private static string _dbJobSelect = "SELECT jID, jAddress FROM Job";

public static DataTable GetJobs(string jAddress)
{
    DataTable dt = ExecuteDataTable(_dbJobSelect);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jAddress))
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("jAddress = '{0}'", jAddress);
        dt = dv.ToTable();
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid this error by specifying the types of parameters which are passed to the query. So all you need to do is:

```
pjAddress.DbType = DbType.String;
```

Comment: For me this was the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it to `varchar`

```
SELECT jID FROM Job WHERE jAddress = @jAddress 
    OR cast(@jAddress AS varchar(4000)) IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem recently and discovered that I hadn't actually added the query parameter to the `IDbCommand`.  I'm not sure what your `ExecuteDataTable` method looks like, but my code was similar to the following (where `db` is an `IDbConnection` instance):

```
var sql = "SELECT jID FROM Job WHERE jAddress = @jAddress OR @jAddress IS NULL";
var cmd = db.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = sql;
var param = cmd.CreateParameter();
param.DbType = DbType.String;
param.ParameterName = "@jAddress";
param.Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(pjAddress) ? DBNull.Value : (object)pjAddress;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);  // THIS WAS THE STEP I WAS MISSING!!!
// ... rest of the code to execute the query and load the results ...
```

After adding the `cmd.Parameters.Add(param)`, the exception disappeared.